# Using lambda with user input list

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to use the lambda function with a user input list to multiply all numbers inputted. If 3,4,5 are inputted, I want the product of those numbers. I have also tried using operator.mult with no luck.

```
import operator
import functools

mult_list = list()
mult_list.append(input("Enter numbers seperated by a comma: "))
mult = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [mult_list])
print mult
```

I usually get ([whatever numbers inputted]) as a result with both lambda and operator.mult. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `input("Enter numbers seperated by a comma: ")` is a string, not a list of numbers. you have to split and map to numbers first.

Comment: you can do something like this  map(int,"1,2,3".split(","))

edit: nvm, the input seems to be a type tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you are sending to `functools.reduce` is `[mult_list]`, which is a singleton `list` wrapping *another* singleton `list` that contains either a string in Python 3 or a `tuple` in Python 2. The string does not have a separate element for each number, and it contains strings, not numbers. It would work better in Python 2, since it would evaluate the `tuple` from `input`. However, `reduce` is a built-in in Python 2 and does not need an import.

In Python 2:

```
>>> mult_list = input("Enter numbers seperated by a comma: ")
Enter numbers seperated by a comma: 1, 2, 3
>>> mult = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, mult_list)
>>> print mult
6
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> import functools
>>> mult_list = list(map(int, input("Enter numbers seperated by a comma: ").split(',')))
Enter numbers seperated by a comma: 1, 2, 3
>>> mult = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, mult_list)
>>> print(mult)
6
```

However, you should abandon `reduce` and do it like this:

```
>>> mult_list = list(map(int, input("Enter numbers seperated by a comma: ").split(',')))
Enter numbers seperated by a comma: 1, 2, 3
>>> num = 1
>>> for i in mult_list:
...     num *= i
...
>>> print(num)
6
```

In Python 2, replace that `input` with `raw_input`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I took out the `reduce` and did the for loop, works perfectly. Just out of curiosity, why do you recommend replacing `reduce` with the loop?

Comment: @JJ_Marrs - As noted in the relevant [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3100/), see [here](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.pdf) and [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196). In a nutshell, it is more complex to write, read, and use, causing bugs with no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Python3, the result of `input` is a string, so needs to be `split` and converted to a list of `int`

```
import functools

inp = input("Enter numbers seperated by a comma: ")
mult_list = [int(x) for x in inp.split(',')]

mult = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [mult_list])
print(mult)
```

Since you are using `print` as a statement, it's probable you are using Python2.x In which case you need to use `raw_input`

```
inp = raw_input("Enter numbers seperated by a comma: ")
```

Using `input` in Python2 is generally a bad idea as it will eval whatever is entered (not just comma separated ints)